# Error Can't process attribute android:fillColor

Tags: java, android

A qué se debe este error?, no me aparece ningún detalle en el logcat ni nada, ya que ocurre el error antes de que inicie la app.

Este es el error:

```
Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/colorIcon": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation.
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error indica en español:

> No puede procesar el atributo android:fillColor="@color/colorIcon":
>   Las referencias a otros recursos no son compatibles con la generación
>   de PNG en tiempo de creación

**el problema aquí es que estas usando gráficos vectoriales**, en lugar de imágenes .jpg, .png, etc. **y estos no están soportados por tu aplicación.**

Agrega en tu `build.gradle` el soporte para usar gráficos vectoriales

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

definelo de esta forma:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ...
    }
}
```